# Unload a div when image loads

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="side">
    <div class="imageFill"></div>
    <img src="/path/to/image1.jpg" class="sideImage">
</div>
<div class="side">
    <div class="imageFill"></div>
    <img src="/path/to/image2.jpg" class="sideImage">
</div>
<div class="side">
    <div class="imageFill"></div>
    <img src="/path/to/image3.jpg" class="sideImage">
</div>
```

What I want to happen is; as each image is fully loaded, I want to hide the preceding `<div class="imageFill"></div>`

Here's what I'm trying but simply doesn't hide them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sideImage").each(function (){
        $(this).bind("load", function(){
            $(this).closest('.imageFill').fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches for a matching element in the ancestor tree, but in your case the `imageFill` element is the previous sibling of the `sideImage` element, so you need to use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sideImage").on('load', function () {
        //it is the previous sibling
        $(this).prev('.imageFill').fadeOut();
    }).filter(function () {
        //if the image is already loaded the load handler will not get triggered, so manually trigger it
        return this.complete;
    }).trigger('load');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverse up the DOM tree and get the first ancestor.

In your case, `.imageFill` is the previous sibling element of `.sideImage` so you can use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev):

```
$(this).prev().fadeOut();
```

instead of:

```
$(this).closest('.imageFill').fadeOut();
```